# Reading PayWave (ISO14443-B format) track information through Android 2.3.3 NFC

Tags: android

I'm trying to **Read Track data for Payment cards** (*PayWave, PayPass*). As per my understanding they follow ***ISO 14443 B***.
With new NFC API,

1. i can connect with IsoDep format without any exception thrown
2. call getHiLayerResponse() - returns nothing :(. Now what?

Later i tried to call transceive() method, but all in vain (i don't know the **APDU** commands).

**Can someone help me how to read/get track details of PayWave or PayPass cards (payment cards)?**

```
if ( NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action) ) {

       Parcelable nfcTag = intent.getParcelableExtra("android.nfc.extra.TAG");
       Tag t = (Tag)nfcTag;
       IsoDep myTag = IsoDep.get(t);

       String s1 = null, s2 = null;
       byte[] b1 = myTag.getHiLayerResponse(); //b1 is not null, but length == 0
       if( b1 != null && b1.length > 0 )
           s1 = new String(b1);

       byte[] b2 = myTag.getHistoricalBytes(); //returns nothing coz its NfcB
       if(b2 != null && b2.length > 0)
           s2 = new String(b2);

       if( !myTag.isConnected() )
       {
           myTag.connect();

           String sData = "0xBB"; // got this magic value from web
           byte []data = sData.getBytes();
           result = myTag.transceive(data);
           if(result != null && result.length > 0)
           {
               s3 = new String(result); // value of s3 will be "m"
           }
       }
}
```

**Any help will be great, please shed some light... Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
byte[] cmd={(byte)0x00,(byte)0xB2,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x0C,(byte)0x00};
byte[] response=iso.transceive(cmd);
```

this is a command to read record. To read the specification of APDU commands refer this

http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4.aspx

These command give a byte array as response. And the format is explained in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

Triangle.io also has an API that allows you to do this free of charge and you can integrate it in your own application. You can download the sample application from Google Play.

Disclaimer: I work for triangle.io

Comment: While suggesting other options is a good idea, I believe in this case the OP specifically wanted a solution for his PayWave issues.